# Java RMI between 2 PCs

Tags: java, rmi

I've successfully implemented the single server-client example [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/rmi/RMI.html) on two different physical machines. I would like to try out this scenario between 2 or more machines :

1. Machine A sends parameters of operation to be performed on machine B to machine B.
2. Machine B executes it and returns status of operation to  machine A.

Do I proceed by:

1. Implement identical copies of my initial program on both machines?
2. How does Machine A know that it has to send the request to machine B and not to other machines? B knows A's IP. But I'm concerned about how it sends the request to B only.
3. Right now, I'm not concerned about any race condition between the 'clients' while they return status.

Any code/online tutorial would be of great help.

Comment: Are you being constrained to use RMI rather than another technique? This seems tailor made for using Java Socket/ServerSocket (a more classical client-server approach).

Comment: @Crollster-Thanks for the reply. I have to use RMI as the requests sent have different implementations on different machines. Also, I'm planning to perform many such operations. RMI seemed to be much easier for this scenario.

Comment: Why is this not client/server?

Comment: @michael667- Here the implementation is on the client doesn't return any variable back to the server. And the example is reverse of my situation- the implementation takes place on the server whereas for me it's on the client's side.

Comment: @PRamesh:The question is slightly vague. When you say _there's no such thing as a client-server_ and then you mention about a request being sent from one machine to other machine ! There has to be a client-server mechanism when two machine communicate with each other.

Comment: @Santosh- Ok. I was under the impression that this scenario basically is instructions being communicated between a bunch of PCs. I'll modify the question then.

Comment: So your clients are really servers. You just have it conceptually back to front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Implement identical copies of my initial program on both machines?

No, you need a client program and a server program.

> How does Machine A know that it has to send the request to machine
>   B and not to other machines?

Because you tell it. You have to tell the client (A) where the server B is.

> B knows A's IP.

B doesn't need to know A's IP. It will get that when A connects, not that it needs it at all: all it needs is the connection, to write the response to. It is A that needs to know B's IP.

> But I'm concerned about how it sends the request to B only.

Because you program it that way. I don't understand your concern.

> Right now, I'm not concerned about any race condition between the
>   'clients' while they return status.

You really must sort out your terminology. Your 'clients' are really servers and vice versa.